# Scratch card game for e-commerce

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, function, splice

This is a scratch card game I modify using script from https://jennamolby.com/interactive-scratch-and-win-landing-page-tutorial/ .
I was trying to make a scratch card game that plan to use on a e-commerce website promotion. So far I can get the scratch function work. The main problem is now I have set up a array pool contain 3 variables that each shows an image. What I want is the array pool will get empty by splicing it one by one and a function will be execute. I was trying to store the array in json but I not sure whether the script is written correctly. Been confuse for few weeks.

```js
var promoCode = '';
var bg1 = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/06/01/22/23/eye-5248678__340.jpg';
var bg2 = 'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4017/4717107886_dcc1270a65_b.jpg';
var bg3 = 'http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/41500000/adorable-puppies-cute-puppies-41538743-590-393.jpg';

var JsonObject, bgArr;

// JS array
var bgArr = [bg1, bg2, bg3];

// Convert (js array) to (json object)
JsonObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(bgArr));

// type
console.log(typeof(JsonObject));

// JsonObject
console.log(JsonObject);


for(var i = bgArr.length-1;i>=0;i--){
  selectBG = bgArr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*bgArr.length), 1)[0];
  console.log(selectBG);
}



if (selectBG === bg1) {
  promoCode = 'SCRATCH400';
  
} else if (selectBG === bg2) {
  promoCode = 'SCRATCH500';
  
} else if (selectBG === bg3) {
  promoCode = 'SCRATCH600';
 
} else if (bgArr.length === 0) {
  alert("No more voucher, back to main website");
  window.location = 'https://www.google.com/';
}


$('#promo').wScratchPad({
  // the size of the eraser
  size: 30,
  // the randomized scratch image   
  bg: selectBG,
  // give real-time updates
  realtime: true,
  // The overlay image
  fg: 'https://cdn.glitch.com/2c225b7b-6134-4f2b-9842-1d5d060d9cd4%2Foverlay.png',
  // The cursor (coin) image
  'cursor': 'url("https://cdn.glitch.com/2c225b7b-6134-4f2b-9842-1d5d060d9cd4%2Fcoin1.png") 30 30, default',

  scratchMove: function(e, percent) {
    console.log(percent);
    console.log(promoCode);

    // Show the plain-text promo code and call-to-action when the scratch area is 50% scratched
    if ((percent > 50) && (promoCode != '')) {
        
      $('.promo-container').show();
      $('body').removeClass('not-selectable');
      $('.promo-code').html('Your code is: ' + promoCode);
   
        var audio = new Audio('https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3');
  audio.play();
        
    }
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.scratchpad {
  width: 450px;
  height: 445px;
  border: solid 10px #27cf27;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/32/Googleplex_HQ_%28cropped%29.jpg");
}

.scratch-container {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .scratchpad {
    width: 400px;
    height: 396px;
  }
  .scratch-container {
    width: 400px !important;
  }
}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .scratchpad {
    width: 290px;
    height: 287px;
  }
  .scratch-container {
    width: 290px !important;
  }
}

.promo-container {
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  width: 450px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn {
  background: #56CFD2;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radiuss: 3px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700italic,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Scratch Card</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="scratch-container">
      <div id="promo" class="scratchpad"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="promo-container" style="display:none;">
      <div class="promo-code"></div>
      <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank" class="btn">Return</a>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function(a) {
        'use strict';

        function b(c, d) {
          this.$el = a(c), this.options = d, this.init = !1, this.enabled = !0, this._generate()
        }
        b.prototype = {
          _generate: function() {
            return a.support.canvas ? void(this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas'), this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d'), 'static' === this.$el.css('position') && this.$el.css('position', 'relative'), this.$img = a('<img src=""/>').attr('crossOrigin', '').css({
              position: 'absolute',
              width: '100%',
              height: '100%'
            }), this.$scratchpad = a(this.canvas).css({
              position: 'absolute',
              width: '100%',
              height: '100%'
            }), this.$scratchpad.bindMobileEvents(), this.$scratchpad.mousedown(a.proxy(function(c) {
              return !this.enabled || void(this.canvasOffset = a(this.canvas).offset(), this.scratch = !0, this._scratchFunc(c, 'Down'))
            }, this)).mousemove(a.proxy(function(c) {
              this.scratch && this._scratchFunc(c, 'Move')
            }, this)).mouseup(a.proxy(function(c) {
              this.scratch && (this.scratch = !1, this._scratchFunc(c, 'Up'))
            }, this)), this._setOptions(), this.$el.append(this.$img).append(this.$scratchpad), this.init = !0, this.reset()) : (this.$el.append('Canvas is not supported in this browser.'), !0)
          },
          reset: function() {
            var c = this,
              d = Math.ceil(this.$el.innerWidth()),
              f = Math.ceil(this.$el.innerHeight()),
              g = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
            this.pixels = d * f, this.$scratchpad.attr('width', d).attr('height', f), this.canvas.setAttribute('width', d * g), this.canvas.setAttribute('height', f * g), this.ctx.scale(g, g), this.pixels = d * g * f * g, this.$img.hide(), this.options.bg && ('#' === this.options.bg.charAt(0) ? this.$el.css('backgroundColor', this.options.bg) : (this.$el.css('backgroundColor', ''), this.$img.attr('src', this.options.bg))), this.options.fg && ('#' === this.options.fg.charAt(0) ? (this.ctx.fillStyle = this.options.fg, this.ctx.beginPath(), this.ctx.rect(0, 0, d, f), this.ctx.fill(), this.$img.show()) : a(new Image).attr('crossOrigin', '').attr('src', this.options.fg).load(function() {
              c.ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, d, f), c.$img.show()
            }))
          },
          clear: function() {
            this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, Math.ceil(this.$el.innerWidth()), Math.ceil(this.$el.innerHeight()))
          },
          enable: function(c) {
            this.enabled = !(!0 !== c)
          },
          destroy: function() {
            this.$el.children().remove(), a.removeData(this.$el, 'wScratchPad')
          },
          _setOptions: function() {
            var c, d;
            for (c in this.options) this.options[c] = this.$el.attr('data-' + c) || this.options[c], d = 'set' + c.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + c.substring(1), this[d] && this[d](this.options[c])
          },
          setBg: function() {
            this.init && this.reset()
          },
          setFg: function() {
            this.setBg()
          },
          setCursor: function(c) {
            this.$el.css('cursor', c)
          },
          _scratchFunc: function(c, d) {
            c.pageX = Math.floor(c.pageX - this.canvasOffset.left), c.pageY = Math.floor(c.pageY - this.canvasOffset.top), this['_scratch' + d](c), (this.options.realtime || 'Up' === d) && this.options['scratch' + d] && this.options['scratch' + d].apply(this, [c, this._scratchPercent()])
          },
          _scratchPercent: function() {
            for (var c = 0, d = this.ctx.getImageData(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height), f = 0, g = d.data.length; f < g; f += 4) 0 === d.data[f] && 0 === d.data[f + 1] && 0 === d.data[f + 2] && 0 === d.data[f + 3] && c++;
            return 100 * (c / this.pixels)
          },
          _scratchDown: function(c) {
            this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out', this.ctx.lineJoin = 'round', this.ctx.lineCap = 'round', this.ctx.strokeStyle = this.options.color, this.ctx.lineWidth = this.options.size, this.ctx.beginPath(), this.ctx.arc(c.pageX, c.pageY, this.options.size / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, !0), this.ctx.closePath(), this.ctx.fill(), this.ctx.beginPath(), this.ctx.moveTo(c.pageX, c.pageY)
          },
          _scratchMove: function(c) {
            this.ctx.lineTo(c.pageX, c.pageY), this.ctx.stroke()
          },
          _scratchUp: function() {
            this.ctx.closePath()
          }
        }, a.support.canvas = document.createElement('canvas').getContext, a.fn.wScratchPad = function(c, d) {
          if ('string' == typeof c) {
            var g, h = [],
              j = (void 0 === d ? 'get' : 'set') + c.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + c.substring(1),
              k = function() {
                g.options[c] && (g.options[c] = d), g[j] && g[j].apply(g, [d])
              },
              l = function() {
                return g[j] ? g[j].apply(g, [d]) : g.options[c] ? g.options[c] : void 0
              },
              m = function() {
                g = a.data(this, 'wScratchPad'), g && (g[c] ? g[c].apply(g, [d]) : void 0 === d ? h.push(l()) : k())
              };
            return this.each(m), h.length ? 1 === h.length ? h[0] : h : this
          }
          return c = a.extend({}, a.fn.wScratchPad.defaults, c), this.each(function() {
            var n = a.data(this, 'wScratchPad');
            return n || (n = new b(this, a.extend(!0, {}, c)), a.data(this, 'wScratchPad', n)), n
          })
        }, a.fn.wScratchPad.defaults = {
          size: 5,
          bg: '#cacaca',
          fg: '#6699ff',
          realtime: !0,
          scratchDown: null,
          scratchUp: null,
          scratchMove: null,
          cursor: 'crosshair'
        }, a.fn.bindMobileEvents = function() {
          a(this).on('touchstart touchmove touchend touchcancel', function(c) {
            var d = c.changedTouches || c.originalEvent.targetTouches,
              f = d[0],
              g = '';
            switch (c.type) {
              case 'touchstart':
                g = 'mousedown';
                break;
              case 'touchmove':
                g = 'mousemove', c.preventDefault();
                break;
              case 'touchend':
                g = 'mouseup';
                break;
              default:
                return;
            }
            var h = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
            h.initMouseEvent(g, !0, !0, window, 1, f.screenX, f.screenY, f.clientX, f.clientY, !1, !1, !1, !1, 0, null), f.target.dispatchEvent(h)
          })
        }
      })(jQuery);

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I assume you are using "wScratchPad" library? I would suggest to put info about it at the start of your post. Probably only someone who used it too will give you any helpful response.

Comment: The scratch pad work fine, what I ask is the splicing of the array pool.